# Kendo upload button css, in kendo window

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I use kendo upload button class for all buttons.

```
<div class="k-widget k-upload k-header k-upload-sync k-upload-empty"><div class="k-button k-upload-button">
<input style="height:38px;width:80px" type="button" value="Kayıt Ekle" /><span>Basvuru Ekle</span></div></div>
```

This works fine for all buttons except buttons in kendo windows. 
when kendo.window first opened, button is like in this picture[image: picture]

Top of the "Dosya Seç" button is not shown.

At second opening of kendo.Window, problem has gone.

At third opening of kendo.window, problem has come again, then gone , then come and goes like that.

This problem occurs only google chrome.

Thanks for all answers and suggestions.

[image]

[image]